# Laravel Nested Loop in blade Templating

Tags: php, laravel-5, nested-loops, laravel-blade

I am building a futsal league website where fixtures and results are to be displayed. The Result Model is like this

```
class Result extends Model {

//
protected $fillable = ['team_1', 'team_2', 'goals_1', 'goals_2', 'date', 'mom'];
```

}

Is there a way that I can loop through this data in blade and group by date?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, there's always a way.

Comment: @Chay22 How? I know the nested foreach could do it, but I don't know how to do a nested foreach to get what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you can do as follows:

```
return view('yourView', [
    'variable' => Result::groupBy('date')->get()
]);
```

[Read more about using models here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent)

[Read more about using QueryBuilder here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries)

In your view, do as follows:

```
@foreach($variable as $row)
    {{$row->date}}
@endforeach
```

[Read more about blades here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#control-structures)